# Error connecting to MongoDB: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js

I try to connect to MongoDB, but I get the error. Here is my code and the error below.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();                        
var mongoose = require('mongoose');             
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                
var database = require('./config/database');            
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

mongoose.connect(database.localUrl);    

app.use(express.static('./public'));        

app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); 

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); // parse 
application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-
HTTP-Method-Override header in the request

require('./app/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

[Heres the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmC24.png)

Comment: Check if your db is running

Comment: Is Mongo running? Post output of `ps -elf | grep mongo`